# MS Word - find numbers, not individual digits

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

The code below searches a MS Word document, extracts numbers, and puts them into Excel.

What I need is if the document has a number like 12345, it needs to extract 12345 and not 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. I have numbers of varying length throughout the document.

I realise it's down to `.Text = "[0-9]"` and my lack of regex but was hoping someone could help.

```
Public Sub NumbersToExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWbk As Object
    Dim xlWsh As Object
    Dim blnStartExcel As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        If xlApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Cannot activate Excel!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        blnStartExcel = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set xlWbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlWsh = xlWbk.Worksheets(1)

    With ActiveDocument.Content
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = "[0-9]"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With
        While .Find.Execute
            i = i + 1
            xlWsh.Cells(i, 1) = "'" & .Text
        Wend
        .Find.MatchWildcards = False
    End With

ExitHandler:
    On Error Resume Next
    xlWbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
    If blnStartExcel Then
        xlApp.Quit
    End If
    Set xlWsh = Nothing
    Set xlWbk = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Comment: use `.Text = "[0-9]{1,}"`

Comment: also have a look here, it might help: https://superuser.com/questions/993886/greedy-match-in-ms-word-regular-expression

Comment: I now get an "Automation Error" - even with the original code that was working before

Comment: You've multiple different issues, which could be hard to solve all the same time. 1. The original question you've posted is independent from VBA, you call Word's find functionality from your macro, first try to find an expression which works there, and if you have it, you can include it in your expression. 2. "automation error" is rather broad, please try debugging your code and give us more specific information, preferably in another question.